# GitHub Action - Unable to add "if" condition in steps

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm using [composite GitHub actions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-run-steps-action), where I want to check the current branch name in composite action's some steps and make the decision on that condition.

e.g.

```
name: main

on:
  push:
  repository_dispatch:
    types:
      - manual-trigger

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout project
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Fetch full project
      run: git fetch --prune --unshallow

    - name: Restore packages
      run: nuget restore -ConfigFile "../Build/Nuget.config"
      working-directory: Projects
      env:
        # ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD is read by the nuget.config credentials section
        ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD }}

    - name: Composite Action - To build solution and execute SonarScanner
      uses: ./Build/build-and-sonarscanner-execution
```

Where in Composite action - I do have a check that Sonar-Scanner should execute only for develop branch, else only project build will gets execute.

```
name: build-and-sonarscanner-execution
description: "Build the solution using msbuild and SonarScanner execution"

inputs:
  # Set of parameters

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps: 
    - name: Restore packages
      run: nuget restore -ConfigFile "../Build/Nuget.config"
      working-directory: ${{ inputs.solution-directory }}
      env:
        # ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD is read by the nuget.config credentials section
        ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD: ${{ inputs.artifactory-password }}
      shell: pwsh

    - name: Install dotnet-sonarscanner package
      if: {{ github.ref == 'ref/head/develop' }}  This is the line where it is throwing syntax error as 'if' is not allowed under steps
      run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 4.10.0
      shell: pwsh
```

[Here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsif) and [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions) are the references I have looked for before applying this if condition here. And that works totally fine if I apply that main.yml, but in composite action yaml file that's not working.

Can someone please share that what am I missing in here?

Comment: `if` is not supported in composite run steps actions, only `run`, `shell`, `name`, `id`, `env` and `working-directory`, see [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runs-for-composite-run-steps-actions), and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/646) where "we don't support setting conditionals" is mentioned.

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminW. In case if it is a right channel, can you please let me know if there is any other approach I can use to achieve what I have explained?

Comment: You can make it a condition in the `run` step; I don't know PowerShell, but in Bash it would be something like `run: "[[ $GITHUB_REF == 'ref/head/develop' ]] && <your command>"`

Answer (score 5):

The above syntax `if: ${{ ... }}` should be fine but it seems that the composite actions do not support conditions yet: https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/main/docs/adrs/0549-composite-run-steps.md

The workaround that Benjamin proposed is working for me:

```
run: |
  if [[ "${{inputs.myVar}}" != "" ]]; then
    aws ...
  fi
  exit 0

shell: bash
```

Comment: This is now supported : https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsif

Comment: It does now seem to be supported. Although note that boolean conditionals need to be if: ${{ inputs.myVar == true }} and not if: ${{ inputs.myVar }}.

Comment: I think it would be useful to update this answer with the syntax reported by @Maggie, since the github documentation about this topic is quite confusing.

Comment: @Maggie IME I needed `inputs.myVar == 'true'`, with the single quotes

Answer (score 1):

`if` used to be unsupported in composite actions, but is now supported (sounds like since [Nov 2021](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-09-github-actions-conditional-execution-of-steps-in-actions/)). See [GitHub's documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsif) on what does or does not work there.

One thing that tripped me up using these is that inputs are all strings, and in particular `if: inputs.enable-deploy` will run the step if `inputs.enable-deploy` is non-empty, including if it's the non-empty string `false`. Use `if: inputs.enable-deploy == 'true'` instead.

Comment: I debated whether to make this community wiki since it's mostly things that I learned from other comments, but eh, I did some of my own legwork as well. Happy to convert if people think that's right.

Answer (score -6):

Try the below syntax:

```
if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/xxxx' }}
```